# T-SQL (Azure), how to see if multiple value are in a set

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql

I have a column `MyColumn` with a value such as "Value1,Value2" (a concatenated string generated using `for xml`). I also have a table valued parameter `@MyTVP` that might have rows with a value such as "Value2" (or several values). The SQL should function something like:

```
where MyColumn in (select col from @MyTVP)
```

I was thinking about writing a user defined function whose call would look something like:

```
where MyFunction(MyColumn, @MyTVP)
```

and the function would split MyColumn into separate values (like C#'s `arr.Split(',')`) and see if those values are in `@MyTVP`.

First, is this a reasonable solution or should I head down a different path?

Second, is there an efficient way to see if the multiple values in `MyColumn` are IN `@MyTVP`?

Comment: You shouldn't store data in that way in a RDBMS system, could you change how the values are stored in the DB or is a legacy application that can't be touched?

Comment: I'm returning them like that in a view. As far as I can tell, it's necessary to avoid getting a gazillion rows returned.

Comment: OK, I though that the data were stored in the table that way, my bad. Anyway note that if possible it would be much faster compare/filter using the original data instead of the concatenated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are playing with fire :) Well, here is the matchbox:
[STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)

```
CREATE TABLE #T (ID INT , Value VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #T VALUES (1 , '1,2,3') , (2 , '4,5,6') , (3 , '7,8,9')

SELECT t1.ID, t2.value
FROM #T AS t1
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Value, ',') AS t2

ID  value
---------
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   4
2   5
2   6
3   7
3   8
3   9
```

Comment: This is nice and simple. Just had to join your query to my table valued parameter's table.

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Data**

```
CREATE TABLE #T (ID INT , Value VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #T VALUES (1 , '1,2,3') , (2 , '4,5,6') , (3 , '7,8,9')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID , Value
FROM (
        SELECT    ID
                , Value
                , Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') SplitedValues
        FROM   
            (
             SELECT  ID 
                    ,Value
                    ,Cast ('<X>' + Replace(Value, ',', '</X><X>') + '</X>' AS XML) AS Data
            FROM    #T
            ) AS t 
                CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/X') AS Split(a) 
    )x
WHERE x.SplitedValues IN (1 ,9)  -- Replace these hardcoded values with your tvp
```